# Adding the button on native dialer

Tags: android

I'm in the process of developing an Android app for which I need to add a button on the native call screen of the android. Is it possible to add a new button to the existing android call screen or should I create a custom screen specific to my app?

Edit: I want to add a button in addition to send the message to the defualt set number.

Answer (score 0):

> should I create a custom screen specific to my app?

Creating your own dialer would be a better option.

This is because even though you can draw your view using the `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` you will still need to:

- get the number the user has just entered **(not dialed)**.
- different devices may have different dialers so your button may not be positioned in all devices.
- you need a mechanism which monitors if the user has opened the dialer. **This will drain the battery**.

> Edit: I want to add a button in addition to send the message to the
>   defualt set number.

You can also create a Home Screen Widget for the same. Why even open the dialer?

Comment: @ SMR can you guide me ,how can i create my own dialer ..?